# Remap Capslock to Shift + Ctrl + Space combination

Tags: keyboard, keyboard-layout, remapping, capslock, ime

Is it possible to remap the Capslock key to a Space + CTRL + Shift modifier combination?

I found out that you can remap keyboard scancodes by editing the Windows registry but that won't allow me to do what I want. I have also looked at the *Microsoft Keyboard Layout Creator* program in order to create a custom keyboard layout but the program won't allow me to re-assign capslock.

The reason I am asking is that I'm using Google's IME for Japanese input and configured it to toggle between *direct input mode* and *ひらがな input mode* with said key combination. Unfortunately the IME settings won't allow me to simply assign Capslock to this action. If anybody knows if it's possible to do that instead, that would actually be even better.

PS. I know there's third-party tools like AutoHotKey that may be able to do that, but I'd prefer a solution that doesn't require a third-party program running in the background.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nevermind, figured it out. [Some guy on Github](https://github.com/chriskempson/windows-capslock-key-japanese-input-toggle) had the exact same problem and re-mapped the Capslock scancode to F15 and then assigned F15 as the key to toggle between direct and kana input. Works perfectly.

Comment: Please have a look at [Can I answer my own question?](https://superuser.com/help/self-answer) and come back two days later and check as answered if you have more than 15 reputation.